# How do I remove a specific sub-object from a json file, for my discord.py api?

Tags: json, discord.py

`HI STAKERS!`

I'm really struggling with json files and I really want to figure them out, to solve this problem I'm having for quite a while, so please help me...

Here's the code I've implemented by far, which includes the problem :
{basically a function for reaction removal evidence in a json file, when called}

```
async def removerr(message, reaction, role):
      with open('reacts.json', 'r') as f:
        messages = json.load(f)

      reacts = messages[str(message.id)]["total rrs"] + 1
      for x in range(1, reacts):

        if unicodedata.name(reaction) in messages[str(message.id)]:
          del messages[str(message.id)][f'reaction({x})']


        if unicodedata.name(reaction) == messages[str(message.id)][f"reaction({x})"]: 
          messages[str(message.id)].pop(f'reaction({x})', None)
        if messages[str(message.id)][f"assigned role({x})"] == str(role):
          messages[str(message.id)].pop(f'"assigned role({x})', None)

      with open('reacts.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(messages, f, indent=4)
```

Basically what I am trying to do is a reaction role removal static function, so when I run my command which goes
`.reaction <messageID> <reaction emoji> <assigned role> remove`
it removes the reaction that's been added **with the same command, but a different arg** - `.reaction <messageID> <reaction emoji> <assigned role> add`, I provided below the data that's been wrote down for it when I added 2 reactions on a single message

The JSON File :

```
{
    "941864271376158770": {
        "IDmesaj": 941864271376158770,
        "reaction(1)": "FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY",
        "assigned role(1)": "Admin",
        "total rrs": 2,
        "reaction(2)": "SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES",
        "assigned role(2)": "Manager"
    }
}
```

Here are stored the

**message id**

**the reaction(total rrs)** <-> the emoji reaction added to the message

**assigned role(total rrs)** <-> the role that's assigned once reacting the message

and **total rrs** <-> the total reactions of the particular message

And what I want my removal function to do is, for example :

if I run the command : `.reaction 941864271376158770 :face_with_tears_of_joy: Admin remove`

I want it to remove the reaction and the assigned role, **specifically** :

```
"reaction(1)": "FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY",
"assigned role(1)": "Admin",
```

as well set the the `"total rrs"`'s value to **"total rrs" - 1** (Example : if there were 2 total rrs before removal, after the removal, there will be only, evidently, 1 total rrs)

Also, if the ***total rrs == 1*** and then I remove that reaction, I want it to pop the whole object, I mean to pop everything because if the specified message has only 1 total rrs, after removal I'd be probably left with only this in the JSON :

```
{
    "941864271376158770": {
        "IDmesaj": 941864271376158770,
        "total rrs": 0
    }
}
```

> I ain't that good at explaining, but if you want to help me, I'll provideany detail needed, thank you!
> Also explaining the steps might be helpful.

> Take care, y'all! **<3**

> **RVZWN**

Comment: Post resolved. :) No need for further help on this subject. Ty y'all!